# React router V3 route does not match if I put one extra letter uppercase

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I am using react router V3, and surprisingly one detail as little as one uppercase letter makes one route to not match. So this does worl:

```
            <Route
              path="payments"
              component={AccountBalance}
            >
              <Route path=":paymentId" component={AccountBalance} />
            </Route>
```

While this doesn't produce any navigation

```
            <Route
              path="payments"
              component={AccountBalance}
            >
              <Route path=":paymentID" component={AccountBalance} />
            </Route>
```

The difference is `paymentID` vs `paymentId`.
[Reading react router v3 docs, there is nothing suggesting that this should happen](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax)

Comment: Can you try with `path="/:paymentId"` and `path="/:paymentID"`? (notice the slash - `/`)

Comment: Does this still happen if you use `/:paymentId` and `/:paymentID` ?

Comment: Will that remove the nested? right now it is `payments/:paymentId`. If I add the slash will it remove the nesting? I'll try it anyway

Comment: Nope, that didn't worked

Comment: You are using old version of react-router? If possible, you should use latest v5. Nested routes are achieved in different manner in v5.

Comment: Well, no, the question is clear about which react router version I am using and I need to use.

Answer (score -1):

The route path must be lowercase, for example, you can use,

```
<Route path=":payment_id" ... />
```

for example, in javascript,

```
let helloWorld;
```

and

```
let HelloWorld;
```

are not equal, becouse theese variables were not written equal.

Comment: you are mixing variable names in JS with the format the route string should have. The V3 docs doesn't say anything about the string format

Comment: The question is about a React Router behavior that is not well documented. It has nothing to do with JS variables names rules.